# Error in File Temp__.rpt

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I made reports using database name Test. SQL Server as backend.
Used DSN. Even configured in ODBC DataSource.
Now I changed my report to mainDb
**Some reports worked fine.** Others throw error when database name changed.

 Error message shown below.
Any solution for this?

[image: Image representing error]

I searched on internet, found similar errors based on invalid login or some implementation error. I don't know what exactly my error means.

My small code is posted here.

```
Private Sub DisplayReport()

    Try

 Dim report As New Summary
 Dim pubdbname as String = "mainDb" '-------This name is correct.'
  With report
            .DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection("bonny", Pubdbname, True)
            .SetParameterValue("@CompYear", PubYear1)
            .SetParameterValue("@CompNo", mComp1)
            .SetParameterValue("@accode", PubAcCode)

            .SetParameterValue("@Trtype", PubTrTp)
            .SetParameterValue("@SBkCd", PubSBkCd)


            .SummaryInfo.ReportTitle = "Summary Report" & "_" & Format(CDate(FromDate.Text), "ddMMyyyy") & "-" & Format(CDate(ToDate.Text), "ddMMyyyy")
            CReports.CRViewer.ReportSource = report
            CReports.Show()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thank You.

Comment: The error message about failing to retrieve data from database usually means there is an error in the SQL query used.  Most often this is due to a table join in your database links.  In your Crystal Report editor if you click on Database > Show SQL query then you can get the SQL query it is using.  Copy and paste that into Query Analyzer on your SQL Server and execute it to check for SQL errors.

Comment: Okay, well I check this and inform you.. I hope you are right.. Thank You. @R.McMillan

Comment: Well, my SQL side scripts are working fine. I used procedures and when I just executed it gives me proper data. I checked it with and without parameters,  all working fine. I searched internet but there is similar error i.e **database vendor code : 201** for invalid login and other. But mine is different  @R.McMillan

Comment: Since you said you sometimes get this error after changing the name of the database; is this change because of a need for a dynamic database selection at runtime, or is it a manual change for using the report with a development database and a production database?  If the schemas are not identical when changing databases, you will need to run the Verify Database command in Crystal Report before it can connect to the database with a different schema than the last time it was verified.